# How to access the operator instance members?

Tags: scripting, operator

I'm testing Blender's scripting, with this simple operator [from the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79b/info_quickstart.html):

```
def main(context):
    print("OPNAME"+":", len(context.scene.objects), "object(s) in the scene")
    print(*[obj.name for obj in context.scene.objects])


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

In the first `print` instruction, I'd like to replace `"OPNAME"` by the name of the operator (supposedly [`bpy.types.Operator.bl_label`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78a/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.bl_label)). However `main` is not an operator's class method, so I can't access the variable directly.

When `execute` is called by Blender, what's the executing context? how can I access the operator instance (excluding passing the value to `main`)?

Comment: How about `SimpleOperator.bl_label` or pass the operator (`self`) to main, or make main an operator method.  Note: the method `main` is only used by way of example is not mandatory. Could also look at `context.active_operator`.

Comment: @batFINGER: `SimpleOperator.bl_label` will work if `main` is only called by this operator. `context.active_operator` is `None`.

Comment: Yes am aware of both counts.  Needs to be a registered and invoked operator for context.active_operator.  As mentioned would simply pass `self` to get the instance.  ie `def main(op, context):` and call via `main(self, context)`

Comment: @batFINGER: I agree the example with a standalone method not receiving a reference to the operator is not a good choice, it makes sense to have everything in `execute` or use a parameter. I'll keep this question just for learning purposes.

Comment: Disagree re choice. Can either call main from the  operator.  or  import the main method from the module to use elsewhere.  Listing the context objects is a  pretty simplistic example... but that's the idea.